# TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' for dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I am running this code in Python 3:

```
fwds_margins = fwds_margins[(fwds_margins.index >= 10)]
```

and it is giving me this error:

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Was running it in Python 2 before, moving it to Python3 and getting this error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-2-compare-string-and-int-why-do-lists-compare-as-greater-than-n

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Python 2 compare string and int? Why do lists compare as greater than numbers, and tuples greater than lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-2-compare-string-and-int-why-do-lists-compare-as-greater-than-n)

Comment: Good thing Python 3 caught this error, because on Python 2, most likely it didn't do what you intended or expected.

Comment: I cannot replicate the provided error with a list of strings. `fwds_margins.index` doesn't return the actual value.

Comment: fwds_margins.index is actually in string

Comment: if `fwds_margins.index` is a string, then what is the `type`of `fwds_margins`? Could you provide a way for us to initiate the variable, so we're working with the same kind of data?

Answer (score 1):

Cast `fwds_margins.index` to int maybe?